# The calculateRoute function often returns an error with the message 'heresdk.RoutingError.internalError' when used with the Here iOS SDK

Tags: heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

When I call the calculateRoute method of the RoutingEngine, the callback often has an error that is ‘heresdk.RoutingError.internalError‘. I don't understand the meaning of the error on the document.

The reference information is as follows:

Here SDK platform: iOS
Here SDK version: Explore Edition 4.12.11.0
iOS version: iOS 16.1
iPhone Device Model: XR

It is very strange that the error does not always occur. When the car's location changes, the app is supposed to recalculate the route from the current location to the destination. However, I am unable to real-time update the polyline on the map because the RouteEngine often returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

The internal error should happen only in rare cases. Try to switch to a newer HERE SDK version. 4.12.11.0 is quite old.